# Pass by reference c++ with class in namespace

Tags: c++, reference, namespaces, args

I am using g++ 4.4.1 and having an issue with passing by reference in my class within a namespace.I have create the test program below that is able to demonstrate my issue and would like if anyone knows why it will not compile

```
#include <stdio.h>

namespace clshw
{
    class hwmgr
    {
    private:
        hwmgr() {};

    public:
        ~hwmgr() {};
        static hwmgr* Instance();
        int Read(int crumb, int& state);

    private:
        static hwmgr* instance;
    };
}

namespace clshw
{
    hwmgr* hwmgr::instance = NULL;

    hwmgr* hwmgr::Instance()
    {
        instance = new hwmgr;
        return instance;
    }

    int hwmgr::Read(int crumb, int state)
    {
        state = true;
        return 1;
    }
}

using namespace clshw;

hwmgr *hw = hwmgr::Instance();

int main()
{
    int state;
    int crumb;

    int ret = hw->Read(crumb, state);
}
```

The error from the compile is:

test7.cpp:30: error: prototype for 'int clshw::hwmgr::Read(int, int)' does not match any in class 'clshw::hwmgr'
test7.cpp:13: error: candidate is: int clshw::hwmgr::Read(int, int&)

TIA,
Keith

Comment: Missing ampersand to pass state by ref in defn.

Comment: The error seems pretty spelled out.

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies on line # 13.

`int Read(int crumb, int& state);`

You have provided a function Read which accepts one int, and one address of int.

and on the line # 30,  `int hwmgr::Read(int crumb, int state)`you are defining a function Read which accepts two int.

Since you are providing different types of arguments, both methods are different. So compiler will give you the error: prototype for 'int clshw::hwmgr::Read(int, int)' does not match any in class 'clshw::hwmgr'

Kindly fix the definitions like this:

on line # 30, write this:

`int hwmgr::Read(int crumb, int &state)`

and tadaaaaa! We have made it work .

Comment: I would disagree, that is not the definition of how reference passing works.  Here is a simple C program where reference passing works okay. <br>#include <stdio.h>

void read(int sig, int& state)
{
  state = 5;
}

int main()
{
  int state = 1;;
  int sig = 5;

  read(sig, state);

  printf("state = %d\n", state);
  return 0;
}

Comment: I apologize. The & does work, but why the second sample worked without it, I do not know.

Answer (score 2):

Your **declaration** of function `Read` is different from the **definition** of `Read` you provided.

The declaration:

```
int Read(int crumb, int& state);
```

And the definition:

```
int hwmgr::Read(int crumb, int state)
```

You have to decide which one you want to use (passing state by *reference* or by *value*), and change the other one accordingly. It seems that the *reference* solution is the only proper choice in this situation, since your function changes the value of the `state` argument.